# HTML elements contained inside div with form-group bootstrap class, display outside the div, is this intentional?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I came across the following online responsive form generator with Bootstrap.

https://codepen.io/erickjones/pen/GZWqRa

One thing I notice that the forms fields contained within 'form-group' div are not displayed within the div.  I checked that by providing a border to the div. It would appear that this so because of the following:

```
<form class="">
```

Is this an intentional way of designing responsive forms?

Comment: This is caused by the grid inside `form-group`, which is floating. You can `clearfix` `form-group` to contain the floating children https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/clearfix/ -- However you may not want to here if the layout is responding as intended.

Comment: Also, I would try swapping the `form-group` and `col-md-6` classes so the grid is wrapping the form groups.

Comment: The layout is responding as expected.  I was just curious to see if this was intentional.

Comment: In this case I don't think its intentional. The examples I'm looking at in the Bootstrap docs show they are clearing floats. For your case I would put the `form-group` containers inside the grid columns, such as `col-md-6` and `col-md-12`. Technically and semantically it makes the most sense here.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful